# "この" vs "こちらの" with regard to implied plurality

Tags: plurals

**この**

> この文型{ぶんけい}は文{ぶん}の作{つく}り方{かた}を示{しめ}している。

**こちら**

> こちらの文型は文の作り方を示している。

1. In all contexts, "この文型..." refers to just *one* grammatical pattern?
2. "こちらの文型..." might refer to one grammatical pattern, or possibly a list of  grammatical patterns (context decides which)? With no context, I feel ambiguity.

**as a side note**:
This might be because " *この* " can be made explicitly plural " **これらの...** , however " **こちららの...** " would just sound too strange?

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24899/7810

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, it refers to one or collective one.
2. こちら can be (1) "this one" or "our side" when the other one ("that one" or "their side") is already present in the context, or (2) a polite form of これ or これら. The latter usage wouldn't be decent in your context. So, that こちらの is "this" opposed to the aforementioned.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "... The latter usage wouldn't be decent in your context." I think that you are saying that, for example, a teacher would never say to students: "こちらの文型...." because the context is not appropriate for a "こちら"?

Comment: As for the former usage, it's nothing strange.